# Line Chart Slider Implementation using google visualisation dashboard and controls

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, google-api, google-visualization

I am facing issue while implementing the slider control using google visualisation contorls. I have implemented numberRangeFilter as a control wrapper. i have datatable like this having following columns.

```
var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Australia', 'china'],
      [2004,  1000,      400],
      [2005,  1170,      460],
      [2006,  660,       1120],
      [2007,  1030,      540]
      [2008,  1030,      540]

    ]);
```

All the column are number type.While drawing this i am getting  x axis data displayed in number format, got reference from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous and corrected this.

Here my code:

```
 var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard( document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
        var yearRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex': 1,
            'width': '100%',
            'ui': { 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'format': { 'pattern':'####','fractionDigits':'0','groupingSymbol':'','showRangeValues':true }}
          },

        });
     // Create a Line chart, passing some options
        var LineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'LineChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 900,
            'height': 500,
            'fontSize':11,
            'hAxis':{'slantedText':'true','direction':'1','format': { 'pattern':'0' }},
            'hAxis.gridlines.color':'#ccc',
            'hAxis': {
                gridlines: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                }
            }

          }
        });
        dashboard.bind(yearRangeSlider, LineChart);
        var dataViewNew = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
           dataViewNew.setColumns([{calc: function(data, row) { 
           return data.getFormattedValue(row, 0); }, type:'string'}, 0,1]);

        dashboard.draw(dataViewNew);
```

Here in this code i have added new column in the datatable which is of type string.

```
var dataViewNew = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
           dataViewNew.setColumns([{calc: function(data, row) { 
           return data.getFormattedValue(row, 0); }, type:'string'}, 0,1]);
```

Now the datatable is like this.

```
['Year' 'Year', 'Australia', 'china'],
      ['2004',2004,  1000,      400],
      ['2005',2005,  1170,      460],
      ['2006',2006,  660,       1120],
      ['2007',2007,  1030,      540]
      ['2008',2008,  1030,      540]
```

Here after drawing the chart x axis come in string format but a new column is added in the legend. please suggest how to remove new column from the legend.

[image]

Comment: change `, 0,1]` to `, 1,2]`

Comment: if i change to this then filter will not work. i need filter with well formated display as shown in graph

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with the example?